# Assigning drive letter to free space failed due to error

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I recently installed Windows 8, and after that I deleted the partition in which I had Ubuntu installed previously. To get the free space back I searched the internet for it, and followed some steps as seen somewhere:

> 1. Disk Management
> 2. Selected the partition
> 3. Right click-> Delete Volume

[image]

So after doing these steps, 
**it automatically extended that 200GB free space with other Logical drives**:

[image]

And now **I am not able to assign or use this free space**, and getting the error in the image I have provided.

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through this.

Right click in the E: drive and then click Shrink Volume it shrink and then give it some name.

Open command prompt with diskpart.

type the folling command like this :

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          698 GB  2048 KB   *
  Disk 1    No Media           0 B      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> LIST PARTITION

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            350 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary             97 GB   351 MB
  Partition 0    Extended           600 GB    97 GB
  Partition 3    Logical            184 GB   297 GB
  Partition 5    Logical             15 GB   482 GB
  Partition 4    Logical            200 GB   498 GB

DISKPART> select partition 5

Partition 5 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> convert dynamic

DiskPart successfully converted the selected disk to dynamic format.

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> convert dynamic

Selected disk is already a dynamic disk.

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     G                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     F   Softwares &  NTFS   Simple       200 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2     H   New Volume   NTFS   Simple        15 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3     E   Entertainme  NTFS   Simple       184 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4     C                NTFS   Simple        97 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 5         System Rese  NTFS   Simple       350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 6     D                       Removable       0 B  No Media

DISKPART> select volume 2

Volume 2 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> extend disk=0

DiskPart successfully extended the volume.
```

here Partition 5 is your shrink volume that come from E: drive .

Comment: Exactly!! solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be best solution, but it can just allow you to use the space.

1. add a new partition on the free space.
2. after create the new partition, choose change drive letter,
3. choose Add, you could either use a new drive letter, or , mount it under other folders, such as C:\mount

Comment: I did the steps you said, but still getting the same error.