# How can I separate free space from extended partition

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

i recently installed windows8, and after that i deleted the partition in which i had ubuntu installed previously, so to get the free space back i searched the internet for it, and followed some steps as seen somewhere,

this was my problem, and 
[Assigning drive letter to free space failed due to error](https://superuser.com/questions/659164/i-want-to-assign-drive-letter-to-free-space-but-failed-due-to-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this.

Right-click in the E: drive and then click Shrink Volume it shrinks and then give it some name.

Open the command prompt with diskpart.

type the following command:

```
DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> LIST PARTITION

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            350 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary             97 GB   351 MB
  Partition 0    Extended           600 GB    97 GB
  Partition 3    Logical            184 GB   297 GB
  Partition 5    Logical             15 GB   482 GB
  Partition 4    Logical            200 GB   498 GB

DISKPART> select partition 5

Partition 5 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> convert dynamic

DiskPart successfully converted the selected disk to a dynamic format.

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> convert dynamic

The selected disk is already dynamic.

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     G                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     F   Softwares &  NTFS   Simple       200 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2     H   New Volume   NTFS   Simple        15 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3     E   Entertainme  NTFS   Simple       184 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4     C                NTFS   Simple        97 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 5         System Rese  NTFS   Simple       350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 6     D                       Removable       0 B  No Media

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     G                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     F   Softwares &  NTFS   Simple       200 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2     H   New Volume   NTFS   Simple        15 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3     E   Entertainme  NTFS   Simple       184 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4     C                NTFS   Simple        97 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 5         System Rese  NTFS   Simple       350 MB  Healthy    System

DISKPART> select volume 2

Volume 2 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> extend disk=0

DiskPart successfully extended the volume.
```

here Partition 5 is your shrink volume that comes from E: drive.